# SUM-IF Formula Issue: Results Not Displaying When Dragging Formula Across & Down

Tags: excel-formula, formula, sumifs

I am using the following SUMIF formula in my spreadsheet:

```
=SUMIF('2020 CBAT Schedule'!$J:$J,!$A2,'2020 CBAT Schedule'!AX:AX)
```

When I attempt to drag the formula down it displays zeros instead of hours from the corresponding tabfrom which it should be sourcing the information from. The same happens when I try to pull the formula across.

When I make the criteria cell (i.e. Cell A2 within "***Roster-Availability***" tab) non-dynamic by removing the ***$*** & ***!***, then the data populates dragging downwards. However, when I try to drag it to the right to populate further date columns, it moves the criteria cell over since it's not static.

I'm not able to  manually update this as I have lots of rows & columns & am looking for a way to fix my formula or possibly see if there is a different formula that could do what I am looking to achieve.

Please see the two screenshots below that show both tabs & point out the data range, criteria, & sum range that is used within the formula.

I appreciate as much help as anyone can provide. Thank you in advance!

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Shouldn't that formula be in H2 not N33 then dragged from there over and down?

Comment: It would be better if the error is reproduced with simple dummy data that can be shared across so that someone can play around to find a solution